# Make form fields editable on button click

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to know how to show form field editable on button click in PHP. Part of my view file:

```
<?php echo Form::label("email", "Email"); ?>
    <?php echo Form::input("email", $userdetails->email,array('disabled' => 'disabled')); ?>
   <br/>  
    <?php echo Form::label("description", "Description"); ?>
    <?php echo Form::textarea("description", $userdetails->description,array('disabled' => 'disabled')); ?>
    <br/>
    <?php echo Form::submit("submit", "Submit"); ?>
    <?php echo Form::close(); ?>
    <a href="../index"><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" ></a>
```

In the page load field should be `disabled`.

If the user clicks the Edit button the hidden field should turn to editable.

Comment: Why in PHP? This could be easily handled on the client side.

Comment: Which one is the hidden field?

Comment: @brbcoding could you please explain me how to handle it using javascript/jquery,any sample would be easy for me to learn

Comment: @PatrickEvans no hidden fields,email and description fields are in disabled mode or non editable mode.On clicking the button make it editable.

Comment: "_the hidden field should turn to editable_" then you should edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: Sure, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/jFYEd/1/

Comment: @brbcoding your solution is what i want.Have a doubt,i need to make 6 fields in editable mode on clicking edit button but each field i had disabled separately and each field having different ids,is any other better solution is their or i should right js for individual field.

Comment: Did you want ONE button to make them all editable?

Comment: @brbcoding one button click,all field editable.

Comment: Sure... http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/jFYEd/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mock Form**

```
<form>
    <input id="inp" type="text" disabled>
    <input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var el = document.getElementById('edit');
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('inp').disabled = false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/jFYEd/1/)**

For usability sake, however, I suggest this:

```
var el  = document.getElementById('edit');
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    inp.disabled = false;
    inp.focus(); // set the focus on the editable field
});
```

Edited: OP commented that several elements will need to be enabled on click.

```
var el  = document.getElementById('edit');
var frm = document.getElementById('myform');
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(var i=0; i < frm.length; i++) {
        frm.elements[i].disabled = false;

    } 
    frm.elements[0].focus(); // put focus on the first element
});
```

**[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/jFYEd/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to set the `disabled` attribute to false

```
jQuery("input[name=edit]").click(function(){
   jQuery("input[name=email],input[name=description]").attr("disabled",false);
});
```

`input[name=email]` selects the email input field

`input[name=description]` selects the description input field